# Simplest way to encapsulate several if statements in class?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have several instances where the client code has to perform an if check, like so:

```
void Client::Method1()
{
    if (flag is true)
    {
        m_Object.DoSomething();
    }
    else
    {
        m_Object.DoSomethingElseInstead();
    }
}

void Client::Method2()
{
    if (flag is true)
    {
        m_Object.DoSomething2();
    }
    else
    {
        m_Object.DoSomethingElseInstead2();
    }
}

void Client::Method3()
{
    if (flag is true)
    {
        m_Object.DoSomething3();
    }
    else
    {
        m_Object.DoSomethingElseInstead3();
    }
}
```

And so on...

I would like to encapsulate the if (flag) checks if possible to be handled internally in m_Object somehow. I thought of using the PIMPL idiom but really all I need is to encapsulate this behavior somehow. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Look at [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: I would recommend looking into function pointers or lambda expressions which might help you get where you need to go.  Basically, you create a function which accepts a flag and two function pointers.  If the flag is true, it calls one function otherwise it calls the other.  Another, simpler idea might be using the conditional operator `(a ? b() : c())`.

Comment: If something and somethingelse have the same parameters, you can set up 2 member pointer tables and call m_Object.ptrTable [flag] ();

Answer (score 2):

You may use [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Something like:

```
class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual ~Strategy() = default;
    virtual void Method1() = 0;
    virtual void Method2() = 0;
    virtual void Method3() = 0;
};

class Strategy1 : public Strategy
{
public:
    explicit Strategy1(Client& client) : client(client) {}
    void Method1() override {client.m_Object.DoSomething();}
    void Method2() override {client.m_Object.DoSomething2();}
    void Method3() override {client.m_Object.DoSomething3();}
private:
    Client& client;
};

class Strategy2 : public Strategy
{
public:
    explicit Strategy2(Client& client) : client(client) {}
    void Method1() override {client.m_Object.DoSomethingElseInstead();}
    void Method2() override {client.m_Object.DoSomethingElseInstead2();}
    void Method3() override {client.m_Object.DoSomethingElseInstead3();}
private:
    Client& client;
};

class Client
{
public:
    Client() { SetFlag(true); }
    void Method1() { strategy->Method1(); }
    void Method2() { strategy->Method2(); }
    void Method3() { strategy->Method3(); }

    void SetFlag(bool flag) // or better: SetStrategy
    {
        if (flag) {
            strategy = std::make_unique<Strategy1>(*this);
        } else {
            strategy = std::make_unique<Strategy2>(*this);
        }
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> strategy;
    Object m_Object;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
m_Object.DoSomething1(flag); // or
m_Object.DoSomething2(flag); // or
m_Object.DoSomething3(flag);
```

Implementation of `DoSomething1`, for instance, would be:

```
Object::DoSomething1(bool flag)
{
    if (flag)
    {
        // Something here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Something else here.
    }
}
```

Doesn't make the code more practical, but still very simple to read plus you moved the flag check a step further (cyclomatically).